# Unit Test code generation

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, code-generation

We have a project developed by 2 years with poorly designed architecture. Now a days there are no any unit tests at all.

Current version of system works satisfyingly but we vitally need refactoring of core modules.

The budget is also limited so we can not hire suffisient number of developers to write unit tests.

Is it the possible strategy to generate code automatically for unit tests which covers, for example,  interaction with data, in assumpion that now system works fine and current system's output can be converted in XML-fixtures for unit testing?

This approach gives us a possibility to quickly start refactoring of existing code and receieve immediate feedback if some core functionality is corrupted because of changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be wary of any tools that claim to be able to automatically determine and encode an arbitrary application's requirements into nice unit tests.

Instead, I would spend a little time setting up at least some high-level functional tests. These might be in code, using the full stack to load a predefined set of inputs and checking against known results, for instance. Or perhaps even higher-level with an automation tool like Selenium or FitNesse (depending on what type of app you're building). Focus on testing the most important pieces of your system first, since time is always limited.

Moving forward, I'd recommend getting a copy of Michael Feathers' [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052), which deals with exactly the problem you face: needing to make updates to a large, untested codebase while making sure you don't break existing functionality in the process.